# Local rsync command to capture a sub-sub-subdirectory of /

Tags: command-line, backup, directory, rsync

The task is simple: create a backup of `/usr/local/bin` and the files within it, and keep the path information.

The following works, but I do not really understand what I have done. I've noticed that the order for the includes and excludes can be important.  Also, "/usr/*" cannot be replaced with "*".

```
# --dry-run is for convenience.
rsync --dry-run -aczvAXHS --progress \
  --include="/usr/local" \
  --exclude="/usr/*" \
  --include="/usr/local/bin" \
  --exclude="/usr/local/*" \
  /usr \
  backup/folder
```

Can anybody explain any better way of performing this task?

**--- EDITED TO ADD ---**

As pointed out in the comments, the question could have been more precise.  The answer provided here is expected to work in the context of 'archive a few select [sub-sub-sub]folders of `/`.

Comment: -1: Without saying what you're looking for in a second option, how are we to suggest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following appears to work nicely to list the files and folders needing archival, with exceptions remaining possible:

```
find  \
"/usr/local/bin" \
"/var/www/owncloud/themes/mytheme" \
"/usr/share/cowsay/cows" \
! -path "/var/www/owncloud/themes/mytheme/core/css*"
```

That command can then be run in the following manner and be piped to `rsync`:

```
find  \
"/usr/local/bin" \
"/var/www/owncloud/themes/mytheme" \
"/usr/share/cowsay/cows" \
! -path "/var/www/owncloud/themes/mytheme/core/css*" \
-print0 | \
sudo rsync -0aczvAXHS --progress --files-from=- / "Backups/folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-R` option. From `man rsync`:

> -R, --relative
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server  rather
>                 than  just  the  last  parts  of  the filenames.

**Example:**

```
% rsync -acvzRAHSX /usr/local/bin/ out_dir/ 
sending incremental file list
/usr/
/usr/local/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/bin/foobar
/usr/local/bin/spamegg


% tree 
.
└── out_dir
    └── usr
        └── local
            └── bin
                ├── foobar
                └── spamegg


% tree /usr/local/bin 
/usr/local/bin
├── foobar
└── spamegg
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Of course what was missing from the question was that my snippet was only part of a much larger `rsync` operation, actually rsyncing from `/` with a lot of excludes.  I can use your method for other deep folders such as `/var/www/owncloud/themes` but that will necessitate many calls to `rsync` for those kind of folders.

Comment: @Tfb9 That changes the whole scenario.. Perhaps you should have mentioned all these at the first place..

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to let `rsync` read in a list of files, and sync from `/`:

```
find /usr/local/bin -print0 | rsync --dry-run -0acvzRAHSX --files-from=- / backup/folder
```

`find`'s `-print0` and `rsync`'s `-0` use filenames separated by the nul character - the safest way to handle filenames from input.